# Nextjs api says API resolved without sending a response, but I am returning all the responses

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I implemented a simple page and api to upload a csv file. The file is loaded successfully and stored on the server using the API but I get this error:

```
API resolved without sending a response for /api/uploadv2, this may result in stalled requests.
```

I have checked my code and I am returning responses for everything.

Although I have not implemented detailed error handling conditions as this is just a practice implementation. I am unable to ascertain where this warning/error is being triggered from.

What I have tried is the below code for the API:

```
// pages/api/upload.js

import multer from 'multer';
import csv from 'csv-parser';
import { createReadStream, mkdirSync, existsSync } from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import moment from 'moment';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { pipeline } from 'stream';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const dateFolder = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss');
    const dir = path.join('uploads', dateFolder);

    if (!existsSync(dir)) {
      mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
    }

    cb(null, dir);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

async function parseCsv(file) {
  const results = [];
  const stream = createReadStream(file.path);
  const parser = csv();

  const asyncPipeline = promisify(pipeline);

  await asyncPipeline(stream, parser);

  parser.on('data', (data) => results.push(data));

  return results;
}

export default async function uploadCsv(req, res) {
  upload.single('file')(req, {}, async function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }

    const { file } = req;
    if (!file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Please upload a file' });
    }

    try {
      const data = await parseCsv(file);
      return res.status(200).json({ data });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error parsing CSV file' });
    }
  });
}
```

I was expecting that the data will be returned in the data object but that is also coming in blank

[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJFPp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it simply by adding to the api config externalResolver: true. Following is the code:

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
    externalResolver: true,
  },
};
```